# Returning two dimenstional array as json from mvc controller

Tags: c#, javascript, json, controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to return a 2d-matrix from an MVC controller as json using `return Json(myObject)`.
At the moment I do it this way:
`return Json(myObject.ToJaggedArray())`.

ToJaggedArray method looks like this:

```
public Field[][] ToJaggedArray()
{
    var jaggedArray = new Field[Rows][];

    for (int i = 0; i < Rows; ++i)
    {
        jaggedArray[i] = new Field[Columns];

        for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
        {
            jaggedArray[i][j] = this[i, j];
        }
    }

    return jaggedArray;
}
```

I make js call this way:

```
var data = {};

$.getJSON("/Game/GetBoard", function (json) {
    data = json;
});
```

It all works well except for the fact, that I would like to avoid calling ToJaggedArray() on myObject. Is there anything that I can implement (interface or something) to make it work out of the box? It is important to retrieve two-dimensional array, so implementing IEnumerable is not an option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> implementing IEnumerable is not an option

Judging from the description you've given, sure it is - although I'm not *quite* sure what you're trying to do. But if it's just getting rid of the `ToJaggedArray()` call:

```
public class YourClass : IEnumerable
{
    // ...

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Rows; i++)
        {
            Field[] result = new Field[Columns];
            for (int j = 0; j < Columns; j++)
            {
                result[j] = this[i, j];
            }
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

An example of output (using `int[3,3]` instead of `Field[,]`):

```
[[2,4,6],[1,2,3],[3,7,9]]
```

Each iteration over the `IEnumerable` simply yields the current row as a 1-dimensional array, `Field[]` (or in the example, `int[]`).

**Update: Another option**

More work required, but you could also implement your own `JsonResult` that adds a custom converter to the serializer using [JavascriptSerializer.RegisterConverters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.registerconverters.aspx), but that seems a bit over the top just to get rid of a direct method call.

Comment: Oh, really easy. I haven't thought about enumerating over dimensions the way you did. That solves it, thanks.

I think there is no way to make it work with less code, but if somebody sees it and it's not a variation of the accepted answer, then please post it!